# Angular 4 Dynamically creating components and later retrieving list of created components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to dynamically create several components, some of which may be later deleted. Eventually, I want to perform an action on all components that still exist.

Sample component to be created:

```
class MyComponent {
  ...
  getData(){
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Sample parent class

```
class MyClass { 
   @ViewChild('myContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })
   myContainer: ViewContainerRef;

   createComponent(){
     const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
     const componentRef = this.myContainer.createComponent(factory);
   }
}
```

My attempt to call a method on the components

```
const elementCount = this.myContainer.length;
for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
  console.log(myContainer.get(i).getData());
}`
```

Obviously, this won't work, because `get` returns a `viewRef`, and not the actual component.

I'd like a way to access the component, or a solution using Rx that will provide a way to access all the data for the components that still exist.

Comment: why not manage data with service and do component CRUD base on Data other than counting children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the ComponentRef from you createComponent method:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    @ViewChild('myContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    myContainer: ViewContainerRef;
    children: ComponentRef<MyComponent>[] = [];

    createComponent(){
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);     
      return this.myContainer.createComponent(factory);
    }
}
```

Then add it to an array or some kind of dictionary in the parent component, whenever you create a dynamic child component:

```
children.push( this.createComponent() );
```

To access your dynamic components you would iterate through ComponentRefs:

```
const elementCount = children.length;
for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
  console.log(children[i].getData());
}
```

You would of course also need to track when dynamic components are destroyed, or not needed anymore, depending on your application logic - to find and remove them from the ComponentRef collection.

Also you would probably want to destroy all ComponentRefs when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Thanks!

For anyone else, just a simple equality check will work when looking for elements to remove.

      `removeRef(r: ComponentRef<MyComponent>) {
    this.children = reject((c) => c === r, this.children);
  }`